# Round-Robin Tournaments and Forests

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

In a round-robin tournament with $n$ teams, each team plays every other team exactly once. Thus, there are $n(n-1)/2$ total games played. How many different standings can result? By a "standing" I mean the ordered sequence $(W_1, \ldots, W_n)$ where $W_i$ is the number of wins by the $i$th player. Assume that no game ends in a tie.

I wrote a program to calculate this sequence. For $n$ up to 13, it agrees with the number of forests on $n$ labeled nodes, which is Sequence [A001858](https://oeis.org/A001858) in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/). But I can't see the correspondence between tournament standings and forests with labeled nodes. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The bijection between score vectors and forests on labeled nodes is due to Kleitman and Winston. ([This](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02579176) paper)

A small clarification, your question about the cardinalities being equal was answered by Stanley and Zaslavsky, see Stanley's paper "[Decompositions of rational convex polytopes](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0167-5060(08)70717-9)", but the proof was not bijective.

Comment: 
The polytope of win vectors, by J. E. Bartels, J. Mount and D. J. A. Welsh, is also accessible at

http://www.springerlink.com/content/wr13217220x05726/fulltext.pdf

and also speaks to this.

Comment: The link to the paper by Bartels et al. at `springerlink.com` mentioned in the above [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/84884) is broken, but it can be found at [doi:10.1007/BF02558460](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02558460) ([Zbl 0928.05058](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0928.05058)).